# flashcard flutter app RTDB to firestore transfer

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

so along with an exceptional app dev i have build a flashcard app that uses RTDB to store the progress of every card. i would like to transfer to firestore cloud, can anyone help me write a script for it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to automatically convert an app that uses the Firebase Realtime Database to it using Cloud Firestore. While both are NoSQL databases, their data models are quite different - and there's no way to simply map the data or API calls from one to the other.

Comment: can you shed a little light on the process please?

Comment: It's pretty much the same as starting to build the app from scratch again on the new database that you want to use. Find the same app dev and tell them you want to build the same app again, but now running on Firestore.